# Multithreaded reading line by line a file in Crystal

Tags: multithreading, file, parallel-processing, crystal-lang

I’m beginning with Crystal Lang and I’d like to know if we can make multithreaded reading a file line by line like in C# with Parallel (and the option MaxDegreeOfParallelism)
Thanks

Comment: What you want to achieve? Reading a file by multiple threads is a bad idea and not only doesn't improve the performance, but also add extra headache for thread synchronization (at least at the reading part of your program).

Comment: The closest equivalent to .NET `Parallel` I know of is [`parallel.cr` shard](https://github.com/RX14/parallel.cr).

Answer (score 5):

As far as I understand C#'s `Parallel` correctly, it just implements concurrent (and eventually multithreaded) execution of a number of similar tasks. This is obviously possible in Crystal, even without multithreading. In the stdlib, `HTTP::Server` uses this and there are several shards for job processing for example. Once multithreading lands, this will give us the option to run tasks truly in parallel.
[Issue #6468](https://github.com/crystal-lang/crystal/issues/6468) makes a suggestion how to structure such conccurent tasks, and potentially also configure how many tasks are to be executed in parallel.

I'm not sure what you mean by "multithreaded reading a file line by line". Sharing a file descriptor for simultaneous access from multiple threads sounds like a dangerous idea in any language. Are you certain, C#'s `Parallel` can do that?